# Loading classes and their data from a JAR file isn't fully working?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I didn't really know what to set my question title as because it's so specific and to fully describe it would use up way too much space.

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

I've developed an application, and part of it allows other people to program their own plug-ins for it.  In order to do this, they need to download my library, and extend their plug-in class to one of my abstract classes in the library: `SimplePlugin` and `AdvancedPlugin`.  I also have an interface, called `Plugin` which both classes implement.  In order to dynamically load plug-ins at runtime, I have a `ClassLoader` set up to search for the `Plugin` interface as it combs through the .class files.  I haven't had any problems with this, and I've been able to create plug-ins just fine without any issue.

The problem I've run into is that I decided that I wanted to make my application able to tell what *build* of my library a plug-in is using, so that I can prevent a plug-in from loading if it's using an older build.  So, in my `Plugin` interface, I have a variable set to determine this:

```
public interface Plugin {

    public static String PluginLibrary_BUILD = "0.1.1";

    //methods...
}
```

Here's the other two classes for visual reference:

```
public abstract class SimplePlugin implements Plugin { 

    //methods...
}

public abstract class AdvancedPlugin extends SimplePlugin implements Plugin {

    //methods...
}
```

But every time I load in a new plug-in and try to read the build variable, it always ends up having the value contained within the `Plugin` class inside my **project**  and not (what I assume should be), the value inside the **JAR file** I generate from exporting my plug-in.

Here's an example:

```
//import dependencies from my library

public class TestPlugin extends SimplePlugin {

    public TestPlugin() {
        super("TestPlugin", "v1.0");
    }

    @Override
    public void doOnAction() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

So from here, I'd export the `TestPlugin` class as a JAR file, and it would export the dependencies from my library with it.  Then, I'd drag the JAR file into a folder that I have set up, and from there my application would read it as a plug-in and do its thing.  Unfortunately, "its thing" involves reading my `PluginLibrary_BUILD` variable from my project files and not from the JAR file (maybe?) because if I change it within my project files, the plug-in tells me that its build changed as well.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on, that's just my best guess, so I'm looking for some insight as to why what's happening is happening, and how to solve the problem.  If you want to look at the source files exactly as they're presented, I have them uploaded [here](https://github.com/ShermanZero/StreamSAKsrc/tree/master/src/main/StreamSAKPluginLibrary).  `Plugin` is `StreamSAKPlugin` and the two abstract classes are located under /types and are `StreamSAKSimplePlugin` and `StreamSAKAdvancedPlugin` (I just simplified the names for this question).

If you don't want to go file-digging, here is every file I think you might find important:

[StreamSAKPlugin](https://github.com/ShermanZero/StreamSAKsrc/blob/master/src/main/StreamSAKPluginLibrary/StreamSAKPlugin.java)

[StreamSAKSimplePlugin](https://github.com/ShermanZero/StreamSAKsrc/blob/master/src/main/StreamSAKPluginLibrary/types/StreamSAKSimplePlugin.java)

[StreamSAKAdvancedPlugin](https://github.com/ShermanZero/StreamSAKsrc/blob/master/src/main/StreamSAKPluginLibrary/types/StreamSAKAdvancedPlugin.java)

[StreamSAKFileHandler](https://github.com/ShermanZero/StreamSAKsrc/blob/master/src/main/StreamSAK/misc/StreamSAKFileHandler.java) (responsible for loading in the plug-ins, scroll down towards the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the member with a method? Override it with each implementation, Java has no default interface implementation, so maybe you need to force plugin creator extend some of your abstract classes, not just implement the interface.

Comment: That's what I had tried at first.  It used to be that I had a `getLocalBuild` method that was implemented in the abstract classes, and was in the interface as well, but it still yielded the same result when I called it after creating the `Plugin` object from the .class files when loading everything in.  I just have to be careful about using methods, and how I store the `build` variable, because I want to make sure that there's no way for the user to modify it when designing their plugin.

Comment: Have you tried to remove it from the interface? Why do you put it in there?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm pretty sure I have a good idea of what was going on, and why no matter what I did, I was not going to be able to achieve the result I wanted.  When I was loading my plug-ins, I had to cast them into classes contained by my *current* library build.  So no matter what data that the plug-ins may have been carrying, it was overwritten by the cast.

To overcome this, I reworked my code and file structure a little bit.  Now, my library contains a file referencing its build number.  This way, when my program starts up, it can read the build number from this file, and then also read the build number from that file in any program using the library as a resource.